# what is spring batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

i,d like to know some information about "Spring Batch".
what it is? how can i use it? in which situation  i can use this?
is it related to .xml file or not?
thanks all

Comment: You could try here: http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/

Comment: Please [Read](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/trunk/reference/) and then ask !

Comment: Have a look at tutorial videos:`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CYTj5YT7CZU` `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3kY-Bt8h48`

Comment: The basic concept is that as your application is running on some jobs(Collections of services should be run on background on daily ,weekely,monthly and yearly basis).So if you have 100 classes in serviceImpl then there are 100 jobs to be run.So,who will run the jobs ,of course schedular runs in background.On the basis of parameter supplied to schedular which serviceImpl to run on which time interval it will call that method of serviceIMPl.

Answer (score 2):

From [Spring Batch](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/) website:

> Spring Batch is a lightweight, comprehensive batch framework designed
>   to enable the development of robust batch applications vital for the
>   daily operations of enterprise systems. Spring Batch builds upon the
>   productivity, POJO-based development approach, and general ease of use
>   capabilities people have come to know from the Spring Framework, while
>   making it easy for developers to access and leverage more advanced
>   enterprise services when necessary.

Check video tutorials

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CYTj5YT7CZU

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3kY-Bt8h48

and [Google it](http://bit.ly/12jiFsr)